# Why can't I call my method in my class

Tags: java, class

So the main method in my class looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "stuff";
    VigenereCipher t = new VigenereCipher(text);
    t.stringToIntArray(text);
    VigenereCipher s = new VigenereCipher(text);
    s.intArrayToString(t);
```

The problem is in the first method it takes a string and converts it to an int[] however the problem is when I try to call the second method (which converts the int[] back to a string) it says that t is a VigenereCipher and not an int[]. So how do I call the method in my class so that t is an int[] and not a VigenereCipher object?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the `int[]` returned by the `stringToIntArray` method, not the `VigenereCipher` object. For example:

```
String text = "stuff";
VigenereCipher t = new VigenereCipher(text);
int[] intArray = t.stringToIntArray(text);
VigenereCipher s = new VigenereCipher(text);
s.intArrayToString(intArray);
```

But I’m not sure if this does what you want.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but is the second instance of `VigenereCipher` necessary? Can't we just call `t.intArrayToString(intArray);` ?

Comment: @DrewKennedy I tend to agree. But as the whole snippet seems pointless to me (converting a `String` to an `int[]` to a `String` using an identical cipher?) I did not change it.

Comment: Apathetic. I like it.